Image not working on email when using CreateMIMEEntity and stream.writeText
I have the following piece of code in a web app. It is all working except for the image which results in a broken image (black box with an X). The jpg file is in the Resources\Images area. Why is the image not rendering properly on the email?
    Set stream = s.Createstream()
    s.ConvertMIME = False
    Set maildoc = db.CreateDocument
    maildoc.Form="Memo"
    Set body = maildoc.CreateMIMEEntity
    Set header = body.CreateHeader("Subject")
    Call header.SetHeaderVal("Email Verification")
    Set header = body.CreateHeader("SendTo")
    Call header.SetHeaderVal(emailvalue)
    Call stream.Truncate()
    Call stream.writetext(|<HTML>|)
    Call stream.writetext(|<body bgcolor="white" text="blue">|)
    Call stream.writetext(|<img src="/database.nsf/images/imageName.jpg"><br><br>|)
    Call stream.writetext(|Thank you for registering .......|)
    Call stream.writetext(|This link is active 24 hours (Sat-Thur) or until 10:00pm (Fri).<br>|)
    Call stream.writetext(|<br><br>|)
    Call stream.writetext(|<a href="| & httpserver & |database.nsf/VerifyEmailClick?openAgent&ID=| & clickkey & |">Click here to verify email</a>|)
    Call stream.writetext(|</body>|)
    Call stream.writetext(|</html>|)
    Call body.SetContentFromText(stream, "text/HTML;charset=UTF-8", ENC_IDENTITY_7BIT)
    Call maildoc.Send(False)
    s.ConvertMIME = True

Document Properties shows src="/database.nsf/images/imageName.jpg"> which leads me to think the image cannot be found because the user doesn't have access to the database.
How do I embed the image using CreateMIMEEntity? Can it be done using stream.writetext? Do I need to put the image on an external server and point to that instead? Any and all ideas are appreciated.

Try without the /images part (so only /database.nsf/imageName.jpg). Also, the image must be marked as publicly available (or anonymous must have read access).

Unfortunately that didn't work. We are going to put the image on an external server and point to that. We wanted it to be internal so we could maintain it easier but it just doesn't appear to want to work that way.

If you're sending this as an email, your  tag's href needs to have the full URL of the image, including the 'http://', the server name, and the path to the database. And yes, the user will need Reader access to the database.
Or, you can build a multipart related MIME message structure, read the binary data for the image, base64 encode it, stream it into a MIME part with appropriate headers, create a part for the message body and reference the related image part from the  tag. Syntax for all of this is more than I can recall off the top of my head. (TBH, I usually just refresh my memory of the structure and headers by looking at the source of a bunch of email messages in my gmail account) and then write out the code to recreate the necessary components of the structure.
